# I am losing a number when subtracting cpp integers

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am going through a C++ course and am asked to make a simple cashier program with change in dollars and cents, separately.

In doing so, I came across an instance where if I `cout` my calculation of `cout<<change*100 - dollars*100<<endl;` I get 40 cents correctly.

But when I set the int `cents = change * 100 - dollars * 100;` Then `cout<<cents<<endl;` I get 39.

Is this because of the data types I am using have some unintended consequences that I'm not aware of? Here is the whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double price, paymentAmount, change;
    int dollars, cents;

    price = 23.00;
    paymentAmount = 24.40;

    cout<<"total: "<<price<<endl;
    cout<<"paid: "<<paymentAmount<<endl;

    change = paymentAmount-price;

    dollars = change; // implicit conversion from double -> int
    cents = change * 100 - dollars * 100;

    cout<<"dollars: "<<dollars<<endl;
    cout<<"cents: "<<change*100 - dollars*100<<endl; // outputs 40
    cout<<"cents: "<<cents<<endl; // outputs 39

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Edit:

Turns out this is from converting the double to int, which truncates the decimals. My number was something like 39.99999 but was truncated to 39 when converting to int. I think that conversion aspect makes this a non duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: For future reference, never use standard floating point types and arithmetics when dealing with money. It might be enough for a simple beginners exercise but once you're past being a beginner don't do it.

Comment: Save the currency as cents in an integer/long long instead, to avoid loss of information, caused by the floating point format using large numbers or periodic cents (because 1/10 or 1/100 cannot be exactly stored in binary firmat).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since the issue is due to the conversion to int, resulting in the truncation rather than rounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `change*100 - dollars*100` is a floating point expression of type `double`. This will be *rounded* when you output it.

But when you assign it to an integer variable, the floating point value is *truncated*, where the decimals are simply cut away. So if you have something like `39.9` that will be rounded to `40` and truncated to `39`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a clearer answer for a beginner because it highlights the rounding vs truncating

Answer (score 0):

It is related to `decimal point precision`. In line `cents = change * 100 - dollars * 100;` precision is lost because result is converted into `int`. But in line `cout<<"cents: "<<change*100 - dollars*100<<endl;` result is in `double` so precision is not lost.

You can verify it by following statement

```
double cent2=change * 100 - dollars * 100;
cout<<cent2<<endl;
```